# 3D: find which pixel on the screen a point inside the scene is displayed on

Tags: 3d, 2d, coordinates, pixel

As the title said. I'm not sure what sort of math go into finding out where an object inside a 3D scene currently is on the computer's screen (assuming the 3D scene is displayed in full screen mode).

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't specified what 3D rendering api you are using (OpenGL? Direct3D?)

Comment: No particular one, I'm asking about the math behind it, not a specific API

Comment: That is a *very* broad question. Google "3D Perspective Projection".